# Retriving posted basic name value pairs posted from android to php

Tags: php, android, post

I am having an issue with having my value displaying that I want echo
I know based on log cat what I am posting is being recieved as the code below returns
the value I am posting from my single basic value pair.

```
  public class JSONTransmitter extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {

String url = "http://mydomain.com/map/";

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
    JSONObject json = data[0];
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 100000);

    JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    try {
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity("json="+json.toString());
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        post.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse response;
        response = client.execute(post);
        String resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);
        Log.i("Response from server", jsonResponse.getString("msg"));

    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

    return jsonResponse;
}
```

}           In my mainActivity

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    HashMap user = new HashMap();
    user = db.getUserDetails();

    try {
        JSONObject toSend = new JSONObject();
        toSend.put("msg",user.get("email").toString());

        JSONTransmitter transmitter = new JSONTransmitter();
        transmitter.execute(new JSONObject[] {toSend});


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

index.php of map

```
if( isset($_POST["json"]) ) {   
 $data = json_decode($_POST["json"]);   
 $data->msg = strrev($data->msg);

 echo json_encode($data);

 }
?>
```

The tutorial I am following can be found at the url below
http://mongskiewl.wordpress.com/2013/10/16/sending-json-data-from-android-to-a-php-script/

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please avoid posting links without context. Links can go dead, making your question useless to future visitors. Instead, isolate the problem, and post a small relevant excerpt of the part where you the problem occurs. You might even find the solution yourself by doing so :) Also, it is difficult to understand what data precisely fails to show on your screen.

Comment: I have updated this post as I acknowledge your suggestions make the post easier to respond to :)

Comment: Add more of the android code and make sure that the echo from php is working.

Comment: I have added additonal android code @Juan-devtopia.coop